# What @Pipe and pipes:[ ] do in Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I know simple | is use for filtering but for this case what's it do?

```
@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    let exp = parseFloat(exponent);
    return Math.pow(value, isNaN(exp) ? 1 : exp);
  }
}
```

and...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'power-booster',
  template: `
    <h2>Power Booster</h2>
    <p>Super power boost: {{2 | exponentialStrength: 10}}</p>
  `,
  pipes: [ExponentialStrengthPipe]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Pipe` is to define a custom pipe. This decorator defines the metadata for the pipe class. See the `PipeMetadata` class:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/PipeMetadata-class.html

The `pipes` attribute of a component to make available pipes into a particular component.

Without specifying them for a component they can be used in it...